# FILE(s) Passed by Shell to Emacs to Visit

Tags: files, start-up, command-line-arguments

The *FILE* mentioned in the title, is what in

```bash
$ emacs FILE
```

or

```bash
$ emacs -file FILE
```

or something else similar.

---

How do I know whether there’s a *FILE* / *FILE*s set for Emacs to visit at startup?  
If there’s such a *FILE*, how do I get its *pathname* or corresponding buffer?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, to me anyway.

Comment: @Drew: for example, someone typed `emacs text.txt` (`text.txt` is such a *FILE*) and then he/she transferred control of the PC to me, but I didn’t know what command he/she used to run Emacs. I want to know which file follows `emacs` of the `emacs text.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

`C-h v command-line-args`:

> `command-line-args` is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `(THE ARGS I PASSED TO EMACS, TO START IT)`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Args passed by shell to Emacs, as a list of strings.
>
> Many arguments are deleted from the list as they are processed.

See also the Elisp manual, node [Command-Line Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command_002dLine-Arguments.html).

Comment: So users need to parse these arguments themselves to find the *FILE* to be visited at startup?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Perhaps someone will provide you with a better answer.